# Is it possible to assign session_id() a value in php?

Tags: php, session

Is it possible to assign session_id() a new value manually?

I've tried the following but it's not working:

```
session_start();
$sessionId = session_id();
echo $sessionId;

if ($sessionId != $ses) { 
session_id() = $ses;
}
```

Comment: from the manual: string session_id ([ string $id ] )

Comment: `session_id() = $ses;` is not even slightly valid. You cannot assign a value to a function. I suggest you [go back to basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php) in the PHP manual if you thought that this was a valid way to do something in any language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php):

```
session_id($sessionId);
```

`session_id()` can be used to either get the session ID or set it by passing in an optional function argument as I have done above.

It is worth noting the following from the manual with regard function call order and session ID character restrictions:

> If id is specified, it will replace the current session id.
>   session_id() needs to be called before session_start() for that
>   purpose. Depending on the session handler, not all characters are
>   allowed within the session id. For example, the file session handler
>   only allows characters in the range a-z A-Z 0-9 , (comma) and -
>   (minus)!

Comment: +1, and well done for resisting the urge to make sarcastic comments about reading the manual before asking questions...

Comment: @DaveRandom actually I've read the manual before asking a question but I'm a beginner and was not quite sure, that's why I turned to stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as per the manual you simply provide a string as an argument to [`session_id([string $id])`](https://www.php.net/session_id)

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the id BEFORE you start the session.

```
session_id('hello');
start_session();
```

However, be careful doing this. The session ID is (generally) a long random alphanumeric string. if you set it to something constant/simple, you've made it much much easier for someone to hijack your users' sessions.

And if two or more people get the same session ID, they'll be SHARING the same session, since this ID is the unique identifier for a particular session. It should be unique for every user, with no duplicates.

Comment: +1 Nice list of cautions here for @wilest about using this method.